# Ending background nohup process?

Tags: pythonanywhere

using PythonAnywhere, I ran a nohup process in the background but forget the PID how can I end it?

I don't have perrmissions to list processes.

Answer (score 2):

There's a "Fetch process list" button on the Consoles and the Tasks pages (they are 2 different lists). Use that to get a process list and you can kill your process from that list.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that  but it wasn't there and eventually seems to have ended after a few hours all by itself. I also read the nohup isn't recommended on pythonAnywhere so will use the scheduled tasks etc in the future.